# Can I strip all the contents of a CSS file?

Tags: css, wordpress, textmate

I would like to strip all the styles but leave all the selectors in the TwentyEleven theme for WordPress, so basically anything between {} in the file. Preferably using Textmate but any guidance will be helpful.

Comment: Why? Empty rule definitions are rather pointless.

Answer (score 1):

TextMate supports multi-line regular expressions, so you should be able to match everything inside `{` and `}`, including newlines, and replace them.

I've never used TextMate, but glancing at their [documentation](http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions) indicates this should be possible.

The regex might look something like:

```
(?m{[^}]*})
```

Replaced with

```
{ }
```

Note: the `?m` turns on multi-line matching - see the docs I linked.

Answer (score 0):

[Perhaps what you want to do a is a regular expression search.](http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions)  This should also show you how to do such a search using TextMate.

Answer (score 0):

If Textmate supports regex replacement then you could replace everything that matches `\{.*\}` with `{}`. Should do the trick :)

Comment: Read the replace part, replace `{*whatever*}` with `{}`